# C++ template style, geared towards easier to understand compiler error messages

Tags: c++, templates

I have heard it been said that unless a good compiler error message friendly style is adopted upfront, C++ templates can make developing and maintaining a project overwhelmingly difficult.

I would appreciate pointers to a resource that describes such a style, and explains it.

Though I seek specific pointers, the question can be interpreted to be open ended, in which case I am open to suggestions on how best to pose it, or remove it from SO altogether, or make it a wiki

Comment: @MarkGarcia  I have to word it better. Meant a coding style that leads to compiler errors that are easy to understand and localize the error

Comment: gcc 4.x generally have improved error messages. don't know any "code style" to make it better, my experience is you have to get used to it and have some patience to go through the messages.

Comment: @arrows it is indeed so much better

Answer (score 2):

Template error messages tend to become unwieldy when a type incompatibility error occurs deep within a series of templates.  Code can be written in such a way that template errors are detected early on using type sanity-check techniques such as `std::enable_if` to ensure that the type used to instantiate a class or function template meets certain requirements upfront.  Indeed, this was the goal of the proposed C++11 `concepts`, which never materialized.

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as to say that was the goal of _concepts_... We have traits and `static_assert` if all we want is to check certain requirements.

Comment: @K-ballo: Improved error messages weren't the *only* motivation for concepts, but the original paper does specifically cite improved error messages as a reason for concepts.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: you meant `weren't` there, right?

Comment: Ok +1 for enable_if. I want to figure out how to write code that fails early in the stack. And I dream of  compiler that will drop me into a REPL like browser on compiler errors so that can browse around to see what type it deduced, but interactively.

Answer (score 2):

andrei alexandrescu's book, modern c++ design, might be what youre looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you can do with coding style is use things like `static_assert` to check the template parameters before you try to use them. [Note: while enable_if can also be useful, I think static_assert is generally more suitable for this sort of task.]

This helps give at least some chance of (for example) an error message something along the lines of "error: X must be an integer type", instead of something like: "error: cannot instantiate `_Detail::_Some_internal_type<double>`", or the (always beloved) "No overload of _Foo takes a parameter of type ZZZ or there was no suitable conversion. Candidates were: [insert 5 pages of seeming unrelated crap here]."